# How do I escape html tags in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-escape-characters

So here is my simplified code :

TestHTML.html

```
<html>
<script src = "TestJs.js"></script>
<body>
<a onclick="var content = 'one<br>two<br>three' ; showContent(content);">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

TestJs.js

```
function showContent(content){

var popup = open("", "PopUp", "width=300,height=200");
var pTag = popup.document.createElement("p");
pTag.innerHTML = content;
popup.document.body.appendChild(pTag);

};
```

Here my requirement is whenever I click on a reference link on page (named `Click here`) a popup should open and display the content sent through `onclick`. The above code is working fine and I get popup result in the form

```
one
two 
three
```

but things go wrong when I try to put angled brackets as text like

```
<a onclick="var content = '<one><br>two<br>three' ; showContent(content);">Click here</a>
```

I got the result for above code in the form

```
two
three
```

i.e text in angled bracket is escaped.

I am aware of the fact that angled brackets are html entities and I need to escape them. I tried to send ASCII for <> i.e `&lt;` and `&gt;` through `onclick` like

```
<a onclick="var content = '&lt;one&gt;<br>&lt;two&gt;<br>&lt;three&gt;' ; showContent(content);">Click here</a>
```

but the text get converted to its original form when passed to javascript funtion and subsequently get skipped in popup(i.e. blank popup).

So my questions here are:

1. How do I escape the html tag in javascript while creating html document?
2. How ASCII text is converted back to normal text automatically when it is passed as argument to javascript function?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle to illustrate your problem? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Quickfix: use `pTag.innerText` instead of `pTag.innerHTML`.

Comment: @GolezTrol — **No**. That will prevent the `<br>` elements being interpreted as HTML.

Comment: @RobinManoli — Stackoverflow has supported [embedded live demos for years](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). If you want a live demo, it is rarely a good idea to suggest a third party site to host it on.

Comment: inline event handlers is a bad choice....

Comment: @Quentin: Nowadays you could use css white-space: pre-wrap to account for cr/lf (I know it's a 5 y.o. comment, just mentioning it for those that come across this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what you have.

1. The character `<`
2. Which needs to be expressed (because it is assigned to `innerHTML`) as HTML so the `<` has to be written `&lt;`
3. But that is *embedded inside an HTML attribute*, where it will be interpreted as HTML when the HTML parser constructs the attribute value in the DOM. `&` has special meaning in HTML, so the `&` must be represented as `&amp;`

So `&amp;lt;`

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot!!! But still don't understand why &lt; gets special treatment when preceded by &amp;

Comment: If it preceeded by `&amp;` then it **isn't** preceded by `&`.

Comment: No ...I mean why at all we have to add  '&'

Comment: Because that's how you represent a character reference in HTML, and a character reference is how you use a character that would otherwise have special meaning (like "start of tag")

Answer (score -4):

Escape them with an inverted bar. \

```
<a onclick="var content = '\<one\>\<br\>two\<br\>three' ; showContent(content);">Click here</a>
```

Test it.

Comment: No. ``\`` is an escape character for JavaScript strings, but `<` and `>` have no special meaning inside a JavaScript string literal. The problem is that the text is being run through two *HTML* parsers. The escaping needs to be done for HTML, not for JS.